# ConTeXt: empty line in enumeration

Tags: context

Consider the following MWE:

```
\setuplayout[backspace=5cm]
\defineenumeration[example][text=Example,alternative=inmargin]

\starttext
\startexample
  One line before
  \startitemize
    \item Test
  \stopitemize
\stopexample
\startexample
  \startitemize
    \item direct itemize
  \stopitemize
\stopexample
\stoptext
```

This produces the following image:

[image: itemizes]

*Question*: Is there a way to remove the blank line in the itemize example (to raise the itemize to the same height as the marginal text appears)?

Some notes:

- I already played around with keys like `nowhite` etc. They do not seem to have any effect.
- As there are some other environments then itemize it would be nice if it could be environment-agnostic. Maybe one could apply some Lua magic (in LaTeX one could do easily with callbacks).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the ad-hoc solution which almost always works in such situations and cancel the whitespace manually using `\blank[back,overlay]`.

```
\setuplayout[backspace=5cm]
\defineenumeration[example][text=Example,alternative=inmargin]

\starttext
\startexample
  One line before
  \startitemize
    \item Test
  \stopitemize
\stopexample
\startexample
  \blank[back,overlay]
  \startitemize
    \item direct itemize
  \stopitemize
\stopexample
\stoptext
```

[image]

To automate this solution, i.e. to insert `\blank[back,overlay]` whenever `\startENUMERATION` is directly followed by `\startitemize` you can use this.  Please don't use this...

```
\appendvalue{\csname ??constructionstarthandler\endcsname enumeration}{\futurelet\next\checkitemize}
\unexpanded\def\checkitemize{%
    \ifx\next\startitemize
        \blank[back,overlay]%
    \fi
}
```

Comment: That looks good. Is there an automated way to insert this whenever there is an itemization at the beginning of an example?

Comment: @TeXnician This solution is only to treat one-off situations.

Comment: I will accept this for now and ask a follow-up question concerning automatization.

Comment: @TeXnician I have added and idea to automate the insertion, but please, don't use it...

Comment: Thanks. It does work. But as it seems to register for all enumerations and you noted "don't use it", I tried to generalize the question and asked it as https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/499602/124577.

Answer (score 3):

First let's try to understand why the extra space is occuring. Roughly speaking, using `alternative=inmargin` is equivalent to

```
\noindent\inmargin{ .. title .. }
... content ...
```

The following example shows the behavior.

```
\starttext
\noindent
\inmargin{Example 1}
\startitemize
  \item This is how enumeration works.
\stopitemize


\inmargin{Example 2}
\startitemize
  \item This works correctly
\stopitemize
\stoptext
```

[image]

An easy fix it to replace `\noindent` by `\noindentation` in `strc-con.mkvi` or locally:

```
\unprotect
\startsetups[\??constructionrenderings:\v!margin]
    \let\\=\crlf
    \noindentation
    \inmargin[\c!scope=\v!local]{\flushconstructionheadbox}%
    \useconstructionstyleandcolor\c!style\c!color
    \ignorespaces
\stopsetups
\protect
```

This fixes the extra new line, but produces a misaglined title:

[image]

This can be "fixed" by removing the `scope=local`:

```
\unprotect
\startsetups[\??constructionrenderings:\v!margin]
    \let\\=\crlf
    \noindentation
    \inmargin[\c!scope=\v!local]{\flushconstructionheadbox}%
    \useconstructionstyleandcolor\c!style\c!color
    \ignorespaces
\stopsetups
\protect
```

Here is a complete MWE:

```
\showboxes

\unprotect
\startsetups[\??constructionrenderings:\v!margin]
    \let\\=\crlf
    \noindentation
    \inmargin{\flushconstructionheadbox}%
    \useconstructionstyleandcolor\c!style\c!color
    \ignorespaces
\stopsetups
\protect

\setuplayout[backspace=5cm]
\defineenumeration[example][text=Example,alternative=inmargin,
titlealign=flushleft]

\starttext
\startexample
  \startitemize
    \item Test
  \stopitemize
\stopexample

\startexample
  Line 1
  \startitemize
    \item Test
  \stopitemize
\stopexample
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation. Only one question: What does `scope=local` do?

Comment: I don't use margin notes so I don't know on the top of my head. A quick look at the code does not provide much insight. I haven't check the documentation yet.