# ConTeXt: Automatically insert a command under certain conditions

Tags: context, automation

This is a follow-up to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/499481/124577. That answer works great (manually as well as automated), but the author noted in terms of automatization "don't use it".

So, consider the example from there:

```
\setuplayout[backspace=5cm]
\defineenumeration[example][text=Example,alternative=inmargin]

\starttext
\startexample
  One line before
  \startitemize
    \item Test
  \stopitemize
\stopexample
\startexample
  \startitemize
    \item direct itemize
  \stopitemize
\stopexample
\stoptext
```

To motivate this: I want to *automatically* eliminate all whitespace at the beginning of the  enumeration.

As this depends on what follows the `\startexample` in this case (e.g. `\startitemize`, `\startformula` create white space, normal text does not), I am interested in setting some constraints. In LuaLaTeX I would register a callback and preprocess the input buffer, but this is disabled in ConTeXt.

*Question:* Is there an automatic way to insert some code dependent on conditions (which can be determinded by pattern-matching input) after a specific command?

Comment: I gut reaction is that this is the wrong way to look at things in ConTeXt. It might be possible to do this using signals (but I need to test that to see if it works).

Comment: @Aditya Well, my gut feeling tells me that there should be some key or setting for it in ConTeXt. But unfortunately, I haven't found one, so I need some different solution. And manually editing hundreds of lines is not a pleasing task…